# How to filter customer by custom attribute using SQL query?

Tags: magento2, customer, sql

The **zd_user_id** is our customer custom attribute.

```
$customerCollection = $this->customerFactory->create();
$customers = $customerCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
    [
        ['attribute' => 'zd_user_id', 'null' => true],
        ['attribute' => 'zd_user_id', 'eq' => ''],
        ['attribute' => 'zd_user_id', 'eq' => 'NO FIELD']
    ],
    '',
    'left'
)
```

How could I get all customers with the attribute **zd_user_id** equal true via SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code='zd_user_id';
```

from this query, you get the attribute id and you also get the `backend_type` for this attribute.

Assuming the backend type is **int**.

```
select count(*) from customer_entity_int where attribute_id=<attribute_id_found> and value=1;
```

If it's **varchar** you can change the query to search in the table
`customer_entity_varchar`.